# Limit server resources for a query in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I want to run a heavy query and somehow limit the resources it uses, so it never affects other client's queries.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible.  You could use sharding to make the query not affect other queries that are reading totally different data, but there's no way right now to prioritize between different queries operating on the same data.